# Laravel SweetAlert not working inside validation fails block

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, sweetalert

I am using realrashid/sweet-alert version 3.1 with laravel 5.8

the issue is when I am using alert after form success or after validation failed its not working here is my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
$rules = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'title_desc' => 'required',
            'desc' => 'required',
            'pic' => 'required',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'title_desc.required' => 'The Short Description field is required.',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $customMessages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            Alert::error('error', 'Validation Errors');
            return back();
        }

        $update_arr = array(
            'title' => "hello",
            'description' => "world",
            'title_desc' => "hello world",
            'added_on' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        );

        StoriesModel::create($update_arr);

        Alert::success('Success', 'Story Created Successfully');
        return redirect('admin/stories');
}
```

in this code I used alert two times and its not working on both conditions
on the other hand

if I am using it like below

```
public function create()
    {
        Alert::error('error', 'Validation Errors');
        $this->data['title'] = 'Stories';
        $this->data['menu'] = 'stories';
        return View::make('admin.stories.create', $this->data);
    }
```

Its working fine

Here is my master layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Toastr style -->
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Gritter -->
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/animate.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    @yield('page_css_tags')
    @yield('page_custom_css')

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    @include('layouts.admin.sidebar')

    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

        @include('layouts.admin.topbar')

        @include('layouts.admin.content_header')

        @yield('content')

        @include('layouts.admin.footer')


    </div>
</div>

<!-- Mainly scripts -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Flot -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Peity -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/demo/peity-demo.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/inspinia.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- GITTER -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Sparkline demo data  -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/demo/sparkline-demo.js') }}"></script>

<!-- ChartJS-->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Date range use moment.js same as full calendar plugin -->
<script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/fullcalendar/moment.min.js') }}"></script>

@yield('page_script_tags')

@yield('page_custom_script')

@include('sweetalert::alert')

</body>
</html>
```

you can see I have added @include('sweetalert::alert') before body tags ends

and here is the blade that extends the master

```
@extends("layouts.admin.master")

@section('title')
    Butterfly | Stories
@endsection

@section('content_header_title')
    Stories
@endsection

@section('page_css_tags')
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/plugins/blueimp/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/plugins/select2/select2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('assets/admin/css/plugins/select2/select2-bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ibox">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>{{ @$record ? "Edit" :'Create New' }} Story</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <form method="post" action="{{url('admin/store_story')}}"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="select2_demo_1 form-control" id="select_seaction" name="seaction"
                                        required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Seaction</option>
                                    <option value="header">Header</option>
                                    <option value="middle">Middle Content</option>
                                    <option value="content">Footer Content</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title">Title</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" class="form-control" id="title" autofocus
                                       value="{{ @$record ? $record->title : old('title') }}" name="title" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title_desc">Short Description</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Short Description" class="form-control"
                                       id="title_desc" value="{{ @$record ? $record->title_desc : old('title_desc') }}"
                                       name="title_desc" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="desc">Story</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="desc"
                                          id="desc"
                                          rows="5"
                                          required>{{ (@$record) ? $record->description: old('desc') }}</textarea>
                            </div>

                            <label title="Upload image file" for="inputImage" class="btn btn-default">
                                <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="pic"
                                       id="inputImage" required>
                                Upload image
                            </label>

                            <div class="lightBoxGallery" id="imageUpload_display">
                                @if(@$record)
                                    <a href="{{asset(@$record->image_path)}}"
                                       title="{{ @$record ? $record->title : old('title') }}" data-gallery="">
                                        <img src="{{asset(@$record->image_path)}}">
                                    </a>
                            @endif
                            <!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
                                <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
                                    <div class="slides"></div>
                                    <h3 class="title"></h3>
                                    <a class="prev">‹</a>
                                    <a class="next">›</a>
                                    <a class="close">×</a>
                                    <a class="play-pause"></a>
                                    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('page_script_tags')
    <script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/blueimp/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="{{ url('assets/admin/js/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('page_custom_script')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (event) {
            $(".select2_demo_1").select2({
                theme: 'bootstrap4',
            });
        });

    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: There aren't any errors with the code you have provided us, which leads me to believe that there is a problem somewhere else. Are you correctly including `@include('sweetalert::alert')` on the necessary views? If you're including it on a master layout, is `admin/stories` properly extending it? Other than that there is not much information to go off.

Comment: Please share the blade template you are using to display the alerts